# Batch File Not Returning Expected Text

Tags: batch-file, arguments

I am making a batch file that looks like this:

```
set /a "number1"="%1"
set /a "number2"="%2"
if "%number1%" GTR "%number2%" echo %number1% Is Greater Than %number2%. & exit /b
if "%number1%" LSS "%number2%" echo %number1% Is Less Than %number2%. & exit /b
if "%number1%" EQU "%number2%" echo %number1% Is Equal To %number2%. & exit /b
```

When I ran it from cmd like this:

```
Calc.bat 4 10
```

It said that 4 was greater than 10. how can I fix it and why does this happen?

Comment: `set /a "number1"="%1"` works but is terrible syntax; use `set /a "number1=%~1"` instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get rid of the vast majority of all those `"` (double quote) characters, they're making the comparison a lexicographical one rather than a numeric one:

```
@echo off
set /a "number1=%1"
set /a "number2=%2"
if %number1% GTR %number2% echo %number1% Is Greater Than %number2%. & exit /b
if %number1% LSS %number2% echo %number1% Is Less Than %number2%. & exit /b
if %number1% EQU %number2% echo %number1% Is Equal To %number2%. & exit /b
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\pax> testprog.cmd 4 10
4 Is Less Than 10.
```

Comment: Let me recommend to use `%~1` rather than `%1` to remove potential quotation marks from the argument(s)...